# Oracle, EF Core creates strange statement on insert into table

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core v7.0.11 with Oracle `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v7.21.11` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core v3.21.110` nuget packages in .NET 6.

I want to insert a new item into a table.

The table looks like following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "xxx"."FRICTION" 
(   
    "TYPE" NUMBER(2,0) DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "V_MIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "V_MAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ALPHA_MIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ALPHA_MAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MU_VMIN_ALPHAMIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MU_VMAX_ALPHAMIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EXP_ALPHAMIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MU_VMIN_ALPHAMAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MU_VMAX_ALPHAMAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EXP_ALPHAMAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "OILED_MU_OFFSET" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "WEAR_MAX_MU_OFFSET" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.01 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "WEAR_MAX_MILEAGE" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 150 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "WEAR_EXP" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 25 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ADA_RATE" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.3 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MIN_VMIN_ALPHAMIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.045 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MAX_VMIN_ALPHAMIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.075 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MIN_VMIN_ALPHAMAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.065 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MAX_VMIN_ALPHAMAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.095 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MIN_VMAX_ALPHAMIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.025 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MAX_VMAX_ALPHAMIN" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.075 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MIN_VMAX_ALPHAMAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.065 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MAX_VMAX_ALPHAMAX" FLOAT(25) DEFAULT 0.095 NOT NULL ENABLE
)
```

When I insert and call `SaveChanges` I get the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 5, column 19:
> PLS-00510: Float cannot have scale

The executed statement is as following:

```sql
DECLARE

TYPE "rFRICTION_0" IS RECORD
(
"OILED_MU_OFFSET" FLOAT(38,17)
);
TYPE "tFRICTION_0" IS TABLE OF "rFRICTION_0";
"lFRICTION_0" "tFRICTION_0";

BEGIN

"lFRICTION_0" := "tFRICTION_0"();
"lFRICTION_0".extend(1);
INSERT INTO "AMEH_RCM"."FRICTION" ("TYPE", "ADA_RATE", "ALPHA_MAX", "ALPHA_MIN", "EXP_ALPHAMAX", "EXP_ALPHAMIN", "MAX_VMAX_ALPHAMAX", "MAX_VMAX_ALPHAMIN", "MAX_VMIN_ALPHAMAX", "MAX_VMIN_ALPHAMIN", "MIN_VMAX_ALPHAMAX", "MIN_VMAX_ALPHAMIN", "MIN_VMIN_ALPHAMAX", "MIN_VMIN_ALPHAMIN", "MU_VMAX_ALPHAMAX", "MU_VMAX_ALPHAMIN", "MU_VMIN_ALPHAMAX", "MU_VMIN_ALPHAMIN", "V_MAX", "V_MIN", "WEAR_EXP", "WEAR_MAX_MILEAGE", "WEAR_MAX_MU_OFFSET")
VALUES (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9, :p10, :p11, :p12, :p13, :p14, :p15, :p16, :p17, :p18, :p19, :p20, :p21, :p22)
RETURNING "OILED_MU_OFFSET" INTO "lFRICTION_0"(1)."OILED_MU_OFFSET";
OPEN :cur0 FOR SELECT "lFRICTION_0"(1)."OILED_MU_OFFSET" FROM DUAL;

END;
```

the code where I add the new friction object to the datacontext:

```cs
var frictionEntity = new Friction
{
    Type = frictionSelectedItem.Type,
    VMin = frictionSelectedItem.VMin,
    VMax = frictionSelectedItem.VMax,
    AlphaMin = frictionSelectedItem.AlphaMin,
    AlphaMax = frictionSelectedItem.AlphaMax,
    MuVminAlphamin = frictionSelectedItem.MuVminAlphamin,
    MuVmaxAlphamin = frictionSelectedItem.MuVmaxAlphamin,
    ExpAlphamin = frictionSelectedItem.ExpAlphamin,
    MuVminAlphamax = frictionSelectedItem.MuVminAlphamax,
    MuVmaxAlphamax = frictionSelectedItem.MuVmaxAlphamax,
    ExpAlphamax = frictionSelectedItem.ExpAlphamax,
    OiledMuOffset = frictionSelectedItem.OiledMuOffset,
    WearMaxMuOffset = frictionSelectedItem.WearMaxMuOffset,
    WearMaxMileage = frictionSelectedItem.WearMaxMileage,
    WearExp = frictionSelectedItem.WearExp,
    AdaRate = frictionSelectedItem.AdaRate,
    MinVminAlphamin = frictionSelectedItem.MinVminAlphamin,
    MaxVminAlphamin = frictionSelectedItem.MaxVminAlphamin,
    MinVminAlphamax = frictionSelectedItem.MinVminAlphamax,
    MaxVminAlphamax = frictionSelectedItem.MaxVminAlphamax,
    MinVmaxAlphamin = frictionSelectedItem.MinVmaxAlphamin,
    MaxVmaxAlphamin = frictionSelectedItem.MaxVmaxAlphamin,
    MinVmaxAlphamax = frictionSelectedItem.MinVmaxAlphamax,
    MaxVmaxAlphamax = frictionSelectedItem.MaxVmaxAlphamax
};

context.Frictions.Add(frictionEntity);

context.SaveChanges();
```

My question is: why does Entity Framework Core create such a strange query instead of only an `INSERT` statement, and why is this only when `OILED_MU_OFFSET` is 0?

### Update

The mapping is as following:

```cs
[Table("FRICTION")]
public partial class Friction
{
    [Key]
    [Column("TYPE")]
    [Precision(2)]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [Column("V_MIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double VMin { get; set; }

    [Column("V_MAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double VMax { get; set; }

    [Column("ALPHA_MIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double AlphaMin { get; set; }

    [Column("ALPHA_MAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double AlphaMax { get; set; }

    [Column("MU_VMIN_ALPHAMIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MuVminAlphamin { get; set; }

    [Column("MU_VMAX_ALPHAMIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MuVmaxAlphamin { get; set; }

    [Column("EXP_ALPHAMIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double ExpAlphamin { get; set; }

    [Column("MU_VMIN_ALPHAMAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MuVminAlphamax { get; set; }

    [Column("MU_VMAX_ALPHAMAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MuVmaxAlphamax { get; set; }

    [Column("EXP_ALPHAMAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double ExpAlphamax { get; set; }

    [Column("OILED_MU_OFFSET", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double OiledMuOffset { get; set; }

    [Column("WEAR_MAX_MU_OFFSET", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double WearMaxMuOffset { get; set; }

    [Column("WEAR_MAX_MILEAGE", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double WearMaxMileage { get; set; }

    [Column("WEAR_EXP", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double WearExp { get; set; }

    [Column("ADA_RATE", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double AdaRate { get; set; }

    [Column("MIN_VMIN_ALPHAMIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MinVminAlphamin { get; set; }

    [Column("MAX_VMIN_ALPHAMIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MaxVminAlphamin { get; set; }

    [Column("MIN_VMIN_ALPHAMAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MinVminAlphamax { get; set; }

    [Column("MAX_VMIN_ALPHAMAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MaxVminAlphamax { get; set; }

    [Column("MIN_VMAX_ALPHAMIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MinVmaxAlphamin { get; set; }

    [Column("MAX_VMAX_ALPHAMIN", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MaxVmaxAlphamin { get; set; }

    [Column("MIN_VMAX_ALPHAMAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MinVmaxAlphamax { get; set; }

    [Column("MAX_VMAX_ALPHAMAX", TypeName = "FLOAT")]
    public double MaxVmaxAlphamax { get; set; }
}
```

in the `DbContext` class in `onModelCreating`

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Friction>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Type).HasName("FRICTION_PK");

    entity.Property(e => e.Type).HasDefaultValueSql("-1");
    entity.Property(e => e.AlphaMax).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.AlphaMin).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.ExpAlphamax).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.ExpAlphamin).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.MuVmaxAlphamax).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.MuVmaxAlphamin).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.MuVminAlphamax).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.MuVminAlphamin).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.OiledMuOffset).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.VMax).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.VMin).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
    entity.Property(e => e.WearExp).HasDefaultValueSql("25");
    entity.Property(e => e.WearMaxMileage).HasDefaultValueSql("150");
    entity.Property(e => e.WearMaxMuOffset).HasDefaultValueSql("0.01");
    entity.Property(e => e.AdaRate).HasDefaultValueSql("0.3");
    entity.Property(e => e.MinVminAlphamin).HasDefaultValueSql("0.045");
    entity.Property(e => e.MaxVminAlphamin).HasDefaultValueSql("0.075");
    entity.Property(e => e.MinVminAlphamax).HasDefaultValueSql("0.065");
    entity.Property(e => e.MaxVminAlphamax).HasDefaultValueSql("0.095");
    entity.Property(e => e.MinVmaxAlphamin).HasDefaultValueSql("0.025");
    entity.Property(e => e.MaxVmaxAlphamin).HasDefaultValueSql("0.075");
    entity.Property(e => e.MinVmaxAlphamax).HasDefaultValueSql("0.065");
    entity.Property(e => e.MaxVmaxAlphamax).HasDefaultValueSql("0.095");
});
```

Comment: Show your entity mapping, especially `OiledMuOffset`

Comment: added the model and also the code for this model in OnModelCreating

Comment: the friction class is partial from the scaffolding, a second partial class does not exists

Comment: Well, for sure it is a bug in Oracle's EF Core provider. But why it is happened when `OILED_MU_OFFSET` is `0` - probably because of `.HasDefaultValueSql("0")`, try to remove  or change to `.HasDefaultValue(0)`.

Comment: The SQL statement is created by the Oracle EF provider, not EF itself. The statement would make sense if `OILED_MU_OFFSET` was a database-generated key. The `RETURNING` clause inserts the database-generated values into `lFRICTION_0` and then, `OPEN :cur0 FOR...` would return the new values to the client. Did you change the `[Key]` attribute perhaps? Are you *sure* this is the actual code that queries the server?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I'm sure this is the actual code. but anyway removing `.HasDefaultValueSql("0")` does the trick

Comment: That's *definitely* a bug. There's no logical reason for the provider to pick the middle column just because the columns have default values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, actually there is a good reason. `HasDefaultValueSql` is SQL string which is not parsed by EF Core, so they do not know what will be returned by database. So they generate `RETURNING` for these fields.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv indeed, but then rFRICTION_0 should include all columns, not just the middle one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I assume they generate such statement only for columns which have default value `0` on time of insertion.